# How do I use the mklink command to create hard links for all files that end in a certain extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file, hardlink

I want to construct a batch file to move certain file types from the Downloads folder to another folder I've designated for that filetype. And then, put a hardlink in the downloads folder for that file.

However, as I suspected my first attempt `mklink /h c:\test\destination\*.txt c:\test\source\*.txt` doesn't work, throwing `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`.

How can I get it to just make individual hardlinks in the destination folder for all .txt files in the source folder?

Edit: I am using Windows 7 enterprise

Comment: You have to create the links one at a time. Use a `for` loop.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to move a file and then create a hardlink because the os won't distinguish between them [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). Just create the new link(s) in the new location with a for loop.

Comment: Actually, I know of at least one case that's not true: OneDrive doesn't detect changes in the hardlink file and upload them, only the 'real' file.